# A 9 dice are rolled at the same Time?what is the possible number of combinations, so that we have ( exactly )one 1 or at (least) a 4 or (both)

Tags: combinatorics, dice

A 9 dies are rolled at the same  Time !
what is the  possible  number of combinations, so that we have ( exactly )one 1  or at (least) a 4 or (both)

My solution ;
Let C = exactly one 1

B = at least a 4

$Let  A = C  \vee  B \vee ( C \wedge B) $

$ \neg A = \neg C \wedge \neg B \wedge (\neg B \vee \neg C ) $

$ \neg A = \neg C \wedge \neg B \wedge \neg C  \vee \neg C \wedge \neg B \wedge \neg B$

$ \neg A = \neg C \wedge \neg B $

$ \neg C$ = no 1 $\vee$ at least two 1's

$ C_{1} $ = no 1 ;

$ C_{2} $ = at least two 1's

$ \neg C = C_{1} \vee  C_{2} $

$ \neg B$ = no  4

$ \neg A =  (C_{1} \wedge \neg B ) \vee  (C_{2}  \wedge \neg B ) $

$  |C_{1} \wedge \neg B| $ = no 1 and no 4  = $ \binom{9+4-1}{9} $

$ |C_{2} \wedge \neg B| $ =  at least two 1's and no 4 = $ \binom{7+4-1}{
7}+\binom{6+4-1}{6}+\binom{5+4-1}{5}+\binom{4+4-1}{4}+\binom{3+4-1}{3}+\binom{2+4-1}{1}+\binom{1+4-1}{1}+1 $

$ C_{1} \wedge \neg B $  and $ C_{2} \wedge \neg B $ are disjoint set

$|\neg A| $ = $ |C_{2} \wedge \neg B| +|C_{1} \wedge \neg B| $

$ |A| = \binom{9+6-1}{9}- |\neg A|$

Is my answer correct ?

Comment: Dice idemtical or all different?

Comment: Why are you using this method? Its tough and chances of mistake.

Comment: they are identical

Comment: that is what mind told me to do :D

Answer (score 0):

Rolling 9 identical dice, in general, corresponds to placing 9 identical balls in 6 boxes.

To take care of the conditions placed, use stars and bars for the following $2$ cases:

- **Zero $1's$, at least one $4$:**
  Consider as if only boxes $2-6$ left, with one $4$ preplaced $\to\binom{8+5-1}{8}$
- **Exactly one $1$:**
  Preplace one $1$, again consider as if only boxes $2-6$ left $\to \binom{8+5-1}{8}$

Add up.